# Unable to find string in text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to simple find if a string exists in a text file, but I am having issues. I am assuming its something on the incorrect line, but I am boggled.

```
def extract(mPath, frequency):
    if not os.path.exists('history.db'):
        f = open("history.db", "w+")
        f.close()
    for cFile in fileList:
        with open('history.db', "a+") as f:
            if cFile in f.read():
                print("File found - skip")
            else:
                #with ZipFile(cFile, 'r') as zip_ref:
                    #zip_ref.extractall(mPath)
                print("File Not Found")
                f.writelines(cFile + "\n")
                print(cFile)
```

**Output:**

File Not Found
C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Python Stuff\Projects\autoExtract\Test1.zip
File Not Found
C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Python Stuff\Projects\autoExtract\test2.zip

**Text within the history.db file:**

C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Python Stuff\Projects\autoExtract\Test1.zip
C:\Users\jefhill\Desktop\Python Stuff\Projects\autoExtract\test2.zip

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Note: `cFile` is the file path shown in the output and `fileList` is the list of both the paths from the output.

Comment: What is frequency supposed to do?  And mPath?

Comment: @RichardKeene nothing as of now, just a placeholder.

Comment: I would be surprised if the `in` operator is failing to correctly report the presence of substrings. More likely that not, there is a clash between your expectations regarding those strings and what those strings actually are.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do...  
def extract(mPath, frequency):   This line does nothing as the params are not used.
    if not os.path.exists('history.db'):  Why create the file empty only to then open it?
        f = open("history.db", "w+")
        f.close()
    for cFile in fileList:   Where is fileList created??
        with open('history.db', "a+") as f:
etc....

Comment: @JohnColeman I believe you are correct. It might be best to use `.readlines()` instead of `.read()` and loop over each line comparing it to your control. Use `rstrip` to ensure there are no escapes or spaces at the end of each line.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter going to try and do that now - thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong flags for what you want to do.  `open(file, 'a')` opens a file for append-writing, meaning that it seeks to the end of the file. Adding the `+` modifier means that you can also read from the file, but you're doing so from the end of the file; so `read()` returns nothing, because there's nothing beyond the end of the file.

You can use `r+` to read from the start of the file while having the option of writing to it. But keep in mind that anytime you write you'll be writing to the reader's current position in the file.

Comment: Wow, I figured it was something simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested the code but this should put you on the right track!

```
def extract(mPath, frequency):
    if not os.path.exists('history.db'):
        f = open("history.db", "w+")
        f.close()
    with open('history.db', "rb") as f:
        data = f.readlines()

    for line in data:
        if line.rstrip() in fileList: #assuming fileList is a list of strings
            #do everything else here
```